# Automatic generator of unit tests in C

Tags: c, unit-testing, code-generation, automated-tests

Is there any automatic unit test case generator available for C language in Eclipse/ Netbeans or visual studio?

Generator in the sense, if I give a file it should generate unit test cases for all the functions. (like jUnit maker in Netbeans).

Comment: I believe that the most common approach is to use a C++ unit testing framework. Trying to write test cases in C would just be horrid.

Comment: I'd question the usefulness of "automatically generated tests".

Comment: The use of automatic generated tests is to reduce the time required to unit test a module.

Comment: @Noufal That just saves you the tedium of writing the boilerplate. But I agree, the time consuming bit is writing the meat of the test. Automatically generating the boiler-plate probably saves ~2% of the time.

Comment: Ah. I didn't notice that it was a Java thing which he used as an example. I dislike code generators in general and the Java world seems to overuse that kind of thing heavily.

Comment: this is still an important question, but moderator seems to like writing the c++ unit test manually...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a tight integration in Eclipse, you should take a look at [CUTE](http://www.cute-test.com/projects/cute/wiki). It is a C++ Unit testing framework, but it is generally not so much of an effort to make C code comply to C++ compilation, and you get access to more inspection tools like this one.

You can take a look at a list of [C Unit Testing framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C) and [C++ Unit testing framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C.2B.2B), but I don't know of any as much integrated in Eclipse as [CUTE](http://www.cute-test.com/projects/cute/wiki) is. (But Eclipse is open source, and nothing stops you from creating a plug-in for another unit test framework :) )

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thanks for the reply]

Comment: useless thing, since CUTE is not generating the tests.

Answer (score 3):

There is [a whole bunch of different C Unit test frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C).
Following are free ones that has generators:

- [API Sanity Autotest](https://github.com/lvc/api-sanity-checker)
- [Opmock](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opmock/)
- [Unity](http://www.throwtheswitch.org/unity)

Comment: `+1` for `API Sanity Autotest`